# How to Search from Multiple column in mysql DataBase with java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jtable

I have follwinig code for search data.

```
public void advanceSearchMethod(String advanceName, int advanceTpNumber, String advanceAddress, String advanceDescription){
    Connection connection=null;
    try{  
        //for connect to database.
        connection=(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/contactbook","root","time1");
        //for communicate with database.
        Statement stmt=(Statement)connection.createStatement();
        String searchQuery="SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE Name LIKE '%'"+advanceName+"'%' AND TelePhoneNumber LIKE '"+advanceTpNumber+"%' OR Address LIKE '%'"+advanceAddress+"'%' OR Description LIKE '%'"+advanceDescription+"'%'";
        rs=stmt.executeQuery(searchQuery);
        contactTableInDefaultForm.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry! Connection Failed");
    }
}
```

No errors in this code.but work catch block. I cannot imagine what I should do. How can I search them?

Comment: what is the exception you are getting .print the exception and tell

Answer (score 4):

You have a major bug -- when you build the WHERE clause, you have spurious ' apostrophes after '% opening-quote & wildcard and before %' closing-wildcard & quote.

```
Your broken code:     "WHERE Name LIKE '%'"+advanceName+"'%'"
Corrected:            "WHERE Name LIKE '%"+advanceName+"%'"
```

But the whole code is not good code, at all -- every single thing is wrong with it.

WHERE clauses should be built up only with the conditions you actually need to search on. And should use PreparedStatement and ? bound parameters, rather than building string-literals into the SQL. (You have built a well-known security flaw.)

PhoneNumbers are strings, not integers. The LIKE pattern for TelePhoneNumber doesn't have a starting %.

DB connection should be provided from one class & method, rather than in every method in your application.

Errors in separate operations (getting the connection/ vs. executing the query and reading results) should be checked & reported separately. Exceptions and stacktraces should *always* be logged (use Log4J) or, at the worst case, output to the console.

The single only thing you got right here, was the variable & parameter naming.

To be honest, you ought to be using Hibernate rather than writing this rickety nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

```
String searchQuery="SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE Name LIKE '%'"+advanceName+"'%' AND TelePhoneNumber LIKE '"+advanceTpNumber+"%' OR Address LIKE '%"+advanceAddress+"%' OR Description LIKE '%"+advanceDescription+"%'";
```

U have added addition single quatation..
Hope this is right answer..